# Which is better to use push or offset in bootstrap?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

Which is better to use `offset` or `push` when i want space between two columns ?

**HTML**

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-2 col-md-offset-1">123 3456</div>
    <div class="col-md-2 col-md-offset-2">123 1234</div>
</div>

<div class="row ">
    <div class="col-md-2 col-md-push-1">123 3456</div>
    <div class="col-md-2 col-md-push-3">123 1234</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would say that `offset` is way more better for basic operations like yours. You should use `push/pull` only to force a block in a specific position which you can't achieve using `offset`.

The `offset` use `margin-left` while push/pull user `left` which you should avoid if you can use `margin-left`.

So for an example it is more better to use like this:

```
<div style="margin-left: 8.33333%;"></div>  // col-xs-offset-1
```

than to use like this:

```
<div style="position: relative; left: 8.33333%;"></div>  // col-xs-pull-1
```

But a complete example is this:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-6 col-sm-push-6">
        Content B
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-6 col-sm-pull-6">
        Content A
    </div>   
</div>
```

On a extra small device (xs) it will look [like](http://jsfiddle.net/paulalexandru/33x9hLn8/):

```
Content B
Content A
```

and on a small device (sm) it will look like:

```
Content A      Content B
```

So if you want to change the order of the blocks, you can't do it using `offset`, you can do this only with `pull/push`. So for this particular cases you should use `pull/push` (when you want to change the order of the blocks) and you should use `offset` for simple operation like in your example.

Comment: could you please provide me an example to understand  ?

Comment: i want space whatever the device is,i don't need to change the position.So `offset` is better right ?

Comment: Yes. offset is the best.

Comment: You should use push only when you want to pull another element back. (to change places)